Creating AWS backup selection using terraform with dynamic conditions
I am trying to create AWS backup selection resource using terraform with conditions being added dynamically.
Code that is I am referring to is taken from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/backup_selection
resource "aws_backup_selection" "example" {
  iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  name         = "tf_example_backup_selection"
  plan_id      = aws_backup_plan.example.id
  resources    = ["*"]

  **condition** {
    string_equals {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/Component"
      value = "rds"
    }
    string_like {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/Application"
      value = "app*"
    }
    string_not_equals {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/Backup"
      value = "false"
    }
    string_not_like {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/Environment"
      value = "test*"
    }
  }
}

I want to parametrized the condition block and pass the values thru a variable, something like below:
module/main.tf
resource "aws_backup_selection" "backup_aws_backup_selection" {
  iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.backup_role.arn
  name         = var.backup_selection_name
  plan_id      = aws_backup_plan.backup_plan.id
  resources    = var.backup_resources
  
  condition = var.conditions
}

module/variables.tf
variable "conditions" {
  type = any
}

main.tf
module "Backup-EC2" {
  source                = "../modules/backup"
  backup_vault_name     = "xxx"
  backup_plan_name  = "xxx"
  backup_rule_name  = "xxx"
  backup_schedule       = "xxx"
  start_window          = "480"
  completion_window     = "10080"
  backup_lifecycle      = "35"
  common_tags           = var.common_tags
  **backup_selection_name = "xxx"**
  backup_resources      = ["arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1:xxx:instance/*"]
  
  **condition {
    string_equals {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/bus-appid"
      value = "u-xxx"
    }
    string_like {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/Name"
      value = "xxx*"
    }
    string_like {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/Name"
      value = "xxx*"
    }
    string_equals {
      key   = "aws:ResourceTag/bus-appid"
      value = "u-xxx"
    }
  }**
  backup_iamrole_name   = "aws_iam_role_for_aws_ec2_backup"
  permissions_boundary  = var.permissions_boundary
  kms_key_alias         = var.kms_key_alias
}

After I am seeing the following error in the plan
Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 876, in module "Backup-EC2":
│  876: module "Backup-EC2" {
│ 
│ The argument "conditions" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 889, in module "Backup-EC2":
│  889:   conditions {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "conditions" are not expected here. Did you mean to define
│ argument "conditions"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.

Using a dynamic block in the module code would become more complex so I want to you if just using the variable here as above is right way to do or I am missing something.
I tried parametrizing the condition block of code because I don't want to hard code the conditions in the module code and want to pass them thru variable.
EDIT-1
Trying to write a simple dynamic block after referring to terraform docs,
dynamic "condition" {
    for_each = var.conditions
    content {
      key = condition.value["key"]
      value = condition.value["value"]
    }
  }

But my confusion is that even with the dynamic block, I would again going to assign a map of values to the block type argument only right?

The condition argument is of block type, so you cannot use the = sign to assign it a value.

condition has to be a block, so you have to use dynamic blocks. You are currently trying to assign a map to a block, which is not something Terraform supports

Ok. Thanks Marko & Thanks Mark.
I will try to convert it into the dynamic block and update here.

@MarkB my doubt is that even with the dynamic blocks, I would be assigning the map of values to a variable only and would be looping thru it right? Is my understanding correct?

This might be the terraform code that you need
Just substitute local.conditions with var.conditions
locals {
  conditions = {
    string_equals = {
      "aws:ResourceTag/bus-appid" = "u-xxx"
      "aws:ResourceTag/bus-appid" = "u-xxx"
    }
    string_like = {
      "aws:ResourceTag/Name" = "xxx*"
      "aws:ResourceTag/Name" = "xxx*"
    }
    string_not_equals = {
      "aws:ResourceTag/Backup" = "false"
    }
    string_not_like = {
      "aws:ResourceTag/Environment" = "test*"
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_backup_selection" "example" {
  iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  name         = "tf_example_backup_selection"
  plan_id      = aws_backup_plan.example.id
  resources    = ["*"]


  condition {
    dynamic "string_equals" {
      for_each = local.conditions["string_equals"]
      content {
        key   = string_equals.key
        value = string_equals.value
      }
    }

    dynamic "string_like" {
      for_each = local.conditions["string_like"]
      content {
        key   = string_like.key
        value = string_like.value
      }
    }

    dynamic "string_not_equals" {
      for_each = local.conditions["string_not_equals"]
      content {
        key   = string_not_equals.key
        value = string_not_equals.value
      }
    }

    dynamic "string_not_like" {
      for_each = local.conditions["string_not_like"]
      content {
        key   = string_not_like.key
        value = string_not_like.value
      }
    }
  }
}


Thank You @Vincent for your response but my concern here is that I won't be able to re-use this module for creating another aws backup selection as conditions are again hardcoded in the locals block. Correct me please if am wrong.

Hi @striker the local block is just used for this example as a sample input. In a real world situation you would ideally use var.conditions instead. Thanks
